# Meaning of "Make what's-her-name feel special this Mother's Day."

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Especially, the "what's-her-name" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much used if someone doesn't know the name of the person being talked about.

"I met what's-her-name yesterday".

Usually being used if the person listening also knows the person.

Answer (score 6):

In general that term is used in place of the actual name when the speaker doesn't know the name. Note that it's pretty flippant in tone; if you don't want that tone you would just say "her."

In that context specifically it's being used as a joke, because of the twist of making someone feel special when they can't even remember her name.

Comment: +1 for explaining the joke. It's especially pointed because the person one would normally try to celebrate on Mother's day is, of course, one's mother...

Answer (score 1):

I think masarah and jhocking pretty much covered it - I would simply add that the joke becomes rather more subtle if one considers that one (usually) knows one's mother's name - but (almost always) never uses it.